# Missing the circle brush in sculpt mode using Blender 2.8

Tags: interface, sculpting

When I open a new sculpt scene it works perfectly, but as I was editing my own model I must have pressed something by mistake and now it's disappeared. The green arrows are pointing to the diamater/radius/sculpt circle thingy that I'm talking about.

[image: that small pink circle lets me know which part of the model my brush is going to affect]

Also, if anyone knows the official name of that pinkish colored circle that would be very helpful, I might be able to simply find it in the UI myself if I knew what it was named... I'm calling it brush circle which is not an accurate description. :)

Answer (score 1):

OK This could be a little bit issue from Users from 2.7 to 2.8
If the sculpt Brush cursor is not visible just go here.
You only need to Brush Settings and Activate the Cursor option on.
This option is in the side bar.
But it also avaliable in the header of Blender.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Go back into object mode and again into sculpt mode. It reappears.