# Where's the sculpt radius?

Tags: sculpting, visibility

When I go into sculp mode the radius that defines your brush isn't appearing. I don't know if it's because I turned it off but it makes it hard to sculp without it.[image: No Radius]

Edit: Never mind it just got working again, I went into edit mode and back into sculp mode and I think that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Blender are you running?

There is a known bug in 2.8 Beta (12/12/2018)

https://developer.blender.org/T59274
[Missing the circle brush in sculpt mode using Blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126532/missing-the-circle-brush-in-sculpt-mode-using-blender-2-8)

Does it reappear if you go into Object Mode and then back into Sculpt Mode?